# SignalR version for .Net 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, signalr

We use .Net 3.5 for our server. If we want to use SignalR with our server, what version of SignalR is appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with 2.0.0 on a 3.5 installation a while back and it worked OK. I only used it for notifications though. Have a look at this link:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nivot.SignalR.Client.Net35/